# Git folder on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Where do I find the `.git` folder on my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment? I ssh'd into my EC2 instance, ran `find / -name ".git"` but it returned no results.

Why do I ask? I normally use the `.git/refs/heads/master` file to get a commit version hash which I put into the end of static files. Example:

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://example.com/theme/global.css?60c9afa3e9" />
```

Can't do that with AWS EB if I can't find the `.git` folder.

Answer (score 0):

elastic beanstalk uses git to fetch the sources, then zips it, uploads it to S3 and unzips it to the EC2 instance. the zip file does not include the git directories, so you won't find them on the instance.
Here're a couple of possible solutions:
1. Create an `.ebextension` file that fetches the latest git version on ec2 (hoping no one has pushed a commit since)
2. Create a different file with an ID and manually populate it in your build process or a pre-commit git hook

Comment: How do I fetch the latest git version on EC2 if the git repository is not there?

Comment: you can setup the git repository remote on your ec2 instance and then use any git command